# Multi Regional and Language sites Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, multisite

I'm using Sitecore and I'm wanting to make my site multi-regional and multi-lingual.

I want the url to be in the following format:

http://www.example.com/ca/fr   (region then language)

http://www.example.com/ca/en

I currently have this in my config:

```
 <site patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
  name="Canada" enableTracking="true" 
  virtualFolder="/ca" physicalFolder="/ca" 
  language="en-gb" 
  rootPath="/sitecore/content/CanadaSite" 
  startItem="/home" database="master" 
  domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" 
  cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" 
  viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" 
  enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" 
  disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
  renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" />
```

I have one complication in my project in the moment, the us version of English is also installed, but I always want the path to be /en.  I don't think it's being used for any content.

Gemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sitecore implementation for URL of a multilingual site is 
http:////

In your case, if you are setting the virtualFolder as /ca,  then your URL would be
http://www.example.com/fr/ca

http://www.example.com/en/ca

instead of the desired /ca/fr and /ca/en

Also the default sitecore behavior is to display  in the url. 
For ex: fr-ca.  However, it is easy to write a custom link resolver so that instead of /fr-ca,  the custom link resolver will output /fr.  But your original issue of language preceding the virtual folder name will not be addressed.

I do not recommend you to change the custom link resolver to output language after the virtualFolder name.  I have not attempted such a customization and do not know what pitfalls you may encounter, need to make sure that preview, experience editor etc all work with such a customization.

The only other thing that you can look into is creating completely different sitenodes in the content tree and then you will need a corresponding site definition to point to that site node.   In this approach the virtual folder in the site definition will be "/ca/en",  "/ca/fr"  and so on as shown below

```
  site patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
  name="CanadaFrench"
  language="fr-ca" 
  virtualFolder="/ca/fr" 
  physicalFolder="/ca/fr"    
  rootPath="/sitecore/content/CanadaFrenchSite" 

  site patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
  name="CanadaEnglish"
  language="en-us" 
  virtualFolder="/ca/en" 
  physicalFolder="/ca/en"    
  rootPath="/sitecore/content/CanadaEnglishSite"
```

This approach will work, you just need to configure each of your site to languageEmbedding="never".  However, i would not recommend this approach as well, because we are completely bypassing sitecore's language versioning - in this approach you are just creating new site node for each language.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rethink using this Structure. I do not know your requirements, but the first problem that you would get is the default Sitecore behaviour.

For example, i have a site with the different domains:

- mysite.com      -> default language : "en"
- mysite.fr       -> default language : "fr-FR"
- mysite.de       -> default language : "de-DE"

if I call mysite.com then the item with the English language will be served.
If I call mysite.com/fr or mysite.com/fr-fr then the French contents (if there is any and depends on language configuration) will be served.

so you should be careful with your url paths

```
mysite.com/[language-culture]/page name
mysite.com/[language]/page name
```

this is the default behaviour of the Sitecore.

Anyway, I do not know your requirements and at the end, you can define an extra site config and map it to the same node in sitecore for english version.

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
name="CanadaEnglish"
language="en" 
virtualFolder="/ca" 
physicalFolder="/ca"    
rootPath="/sitecore/content/CanadaSite" ...

<site patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
name="CanadaEnglishUS"
language="en-us" 
virtualFolder="/ca" 
physicalFolder="/ca"    
rootPath="/sitecore/content/CanadaSite" ...
```

The trick is to give the new Name like **name="CanadaEnglish"** and **name="CanadaEnglishUS"**